# How to enable doxygen support for QML files

Tags: qt, qml, doxygen

I have installed DoxyQML for windows and when i type :
`/**` in my qml file it doesn't appear to be in typical doxygen blue color.How to enable that ? and also in the [DoxyQml](https://github.com/agateau/doxyqml) documentation i did'nt get following line :`To tell Doxygen about Doxyqml you must make a few changes to your Doxygen file.`

Comment: You have made the necessary changes to your configuration file, such as the following:  `FILTER_PATTERNS = *.qml=your\python\path\Lib\site-packages\doxyqml\doxyqml.py`

Comment: Where to find that configuration file ? Usually I just browse my project in doxy wizard and generate doc for my project .

Comment: You have to add all that to that file that generates you doxywizard, that plugin will recognize the text that you place when you compile the documentation, it will not be visible in Qt Creator.

Comment: Thanks and you  mean that I should build doxygen ? so that it can generate final documentation for QML files ? And if I type /** in qt creator for QML file it will not come  and it will only be available for cpp files ... I am using Windows so asking again ...

Comment: Yes, that script will only recognize your comments when you compile the doxygen for documentation

Comment: Thanks .. will try that .. I got following link which explains procedure to generate config file :  https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html